# Validation Process error in propel and PFBC 3.1

Tags: php, forms, propel

I am using Propel and PFBC(php From Builder class). I wrote the validations in xml file using propel php orm (Database) now I want to use them when login button is clicked. It means I want to check the validation of form variables and database validation rules. my xml code look like this

```
<table name="names" phpName="Name">
<column name="nameid" phpName="Nid" type="integer" size="11" required="true" primaryKey="true"
autoIncrement="true" description="Name ID"/>
<column name="name" phpName="Name" type="varchar" size="50" required="true"
description="Name"/>
<validator column="name">
<rule name="required" message="Name is Required"/>
<rule name="minLength" value="3" message="Enter Valid Full-Name, Minimum of 3 characters"/>
<rule name="maxLength" value="20" message="Invalid Entry"/>
<rule name="match" value="/^[\w]+$/" message="No Special Character Allowed"/>
<rule name="unique" />
</validator>
</table>

<table name="relations" phpName="Relations">
<column name="rid" type="integer" size="11" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true"
description="Relational ID"/>

<column name="pnid" type="integer" size="11" required="true" description="name User ID"/>

<column name="rnid" type="integer" size="11" required="true" description="name Relationship ID"/>

<column name="relation" type="varchar" size="100" required="true" description="Relationship"/>

<validator column="relation">
<rule name="required" message="Relationship Type is Required" />
<rule name="match" value="/^([\w])+([\.\w\-]+)+$/" message="Enter a Valid String" />
<rule name="minLength" value="3" message="Enter a Valid Relation Ship"/>
<rule name="maxLength" value="20" message="Invalid Entry"/>
</validator>

<foreign-key foreignTable="names" onUpdate="CASCADE" onDelete="CASCADE">
<reference local="pnid" foreign="nid" />
<reference local="rnid" foreign="nid" />
</foreign-key>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you just want to know how to run Propel's validations then? If so, you can do it like this:

```
$name = new Name();
$name->setName($_POST['Name']); // or however you want to do it
// set other object properties

if (!$name->validate()) {
  $errors = $name->getValidationFailures();
  foreach ($errors as $field => $error) {
    // do something with the valiadtion errors
  }
}
```

Comment: I am getting errors like 'No connection information in your runtime configuration file for datasource [relations]' in C:\wamp\www\relations\propel\runtime\lib\Propel.php on line 573

Comment: PropelException: No connection information in your runtime configuration file for datasource [relations] in C:\wamp\www\relations\propel\runtime\lib\Propel.php on line 573

Comment: Looks like that may be a separate issue, you may want to post it as a separate question with your full schema.xml and build.properties file.

Comment: I got it it's is the exception on log.php file path.

Comment: Another query   I inserted a row to database with out errors now I want to insert second row to database then I got this error Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'profile_U_3'' the error location is BaseName.php can you give any suggestion on this error ??

Comment: Looks like you have a unique key index defined, most likely on a field called `profile` (unless you named it something else). That field must have unique values in the database.

Comment: the primary key with auto-increment will do the table index as unique, and no other unique data entered on registration.

Comment: May I know how to close database properly, and session closing ? I places session on my home page as guest session, it may effect this to occur this error